# C# download file from filestream

Tags: c#, csv, filestream

I want to export my data as csv file. For that I'm using CsvHelper library. But I don't want to have all data in one csv file. The limitation should be 1000 per file.

What I tried for that limitation:

```
var fileStream = new FileStream("/static/export.csv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var stream = new StreamWriter();
var writer = new CsvWriter(stream, config);
 

for(i = 0; i < indexCount; i += 1000)
{
var items = result.Skip(i).Take(1000);
.
.// logic for writing records with CsvHelper
.

writer.Flush();
memoryStream.Position = 0;
byte[] data = memoryStream.ToArray();
fileStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

For example if I have 100000 rows in database, I want to have 100 csv files. How can I download chunk files from stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 1;
foreach (var chunk in result.Chunk(1000))
{
    using var fileStream = new FileStream($"/static/export{i++}.csv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
    var writer = new CsvWriter(streamWriter , config);
    // logic for writing records with CsvHelper
}
```

Comment: It's not enough how much I thank you. You have no idea what awkward things I tried. Thank you very much again. I didn't know .Chunk method